# book suggestion on module theory

Tags: modules, book-recommendation

I want to start module theory from the very beginning. I have a little bit of
idea about what module is but I haven't really solved a handful of problems.
Could someone please suggest me a good treatise on this subject? I badly 
need it.

Comment: What is your mathematical background? What is your motivation for learning about modules?

Comment: During the late 1970s when I was an undergraduate I used to think [**Module Theory: An Approach to Linear Algebra**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0198533896) by T. S. Blyth (1st edition 1977; 2nd edition 1990) would be a good place to begin a serious study of modules. However, I never did such a study nor do I know what others think of this book. Thus, I mention this book for two reasons: (1) as a book to possibly consider; (2) to see if anyone has strong feelings one way or the other about this book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some basic book to start with modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65727/some-basic-book-to-start-with-modules) . Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305486/book-for-module-theory .  Did you even look at all for an answer?

Answer (score 4):

As it was suggested before, *Module Theory: An Approach to Linear Algebra* by T. S. Blyth is an awesome title which covers almost every basic topic of Module theory in a very elegant, clear and efficient way. It is hands down my favorite text in the subject, but unfortunately it has been long out of print and therefore it is expensive and hard to obtain.

I contacted T. S. Blyth a few months ago looking at the possibility of a new edition, or at least, for a Dover reprint or something like that. Recently, Tom told me that he just finished an electronic edition, and I inmediatly helped him with a careful and exhausting typo hunting.
With great joy, I shall let you all know that this venerable text is now available for free (click to download the book from [here](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10023/12643/ModuleTheory_CCBY.pdf?sequence=7&isAllowed=y))!