# Tensor Products -Book Recommendation

Tags: reference-request, modules, tensor-products, book-recommendation

I am reading Module Theory and currently I am stuck at Tensor Products.
Can anyone suggest some books in which a nice and detailed explanation of tensor product of modules is given along with wide range of examples. I would be helpful for me to understand the Tensor Product

Comment: I have read the definitions and proofs of existence and uniqueness but unable to solve problems. So I need to look at some examples

Comment: Maybe [**Module Theory : An Approach to Linear Algebra**](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/handle/10023/12643) by Thomas Scott Blyth (freely available). I sometimes read portions of Blyth's text for additional explanations when I was taking various algebra courses (mostly in the late 1970s), and tensor products are included. Also, regarding supplementary reading for module theory in general, see my comments about [**Theory of Modules**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471994626) by Alexandru Solian [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305486/13130), although has no tensor products.

Comment: But the book Module Theory: An approach to Linear Algebra is restricted to /mathbb{Z} Modules only. So I think they won't construct tensor product of in general. So I guess this might not help me.