# Reference about Tensor Product

Tags: ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

do you know some reference about tensor product of modules, with all elementary properties are proved ?? I want something a bit more explicit than "Commutative Algebra" of Atiyah and Macdonald. Thanks.

Comment: Dummit and Foote's book on algebra is pretty understandable.

Comment: Dummit & Foote has a detailed section on the tensor product.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65727/some-basic-book-to-start-with-modules.